# Trigger to check for duplicate contacts on lead conversion

Tags: apex, trigger

I'd like to write a Lead trigger, to check for duplicate Contacts before inserting the lead, or converting it.

Contacts fields I'd like to check:

- Firstname - should not be the same as the leads name
- Lastname - should not be the same as the leads name
- Email - should not be the same as the leads phone

After checking these fields & failing to find a duplicate, only then should the lead be converted.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're looking for. You want to disallow Lead conversion if there are **any** Contacts matching those 3 values?

Comment: There are free apps on the AppExchange for similar logic... Did I mention they're free?

Comment: if i ll  create lead , before that it check firstname , lastname , email does not exist in contact , if it exit shows some error msg , otherwise lead should be created

Answer (score 13):

Here's one possible scenario for your code. It doesn't catch misspellings, aliases, and other common data entry problems, but it is case insensitive.

```
trigger BlockDupeLeadConvert on Lead (after update) {
    class UniqueKey {
        UniqueKey(string Firstname, String lastName, String email) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.email = email;
        }
        string FirstName, LastName, Email;
        integer hashCode() {
            return toString().hashCode();
        }
        boolean equals(Object o) {
            return toString() == ((UniqueKey)o).toString();
        }
        public override string toString() {
            return String.format(
                'FirstName = \'\'{0}\'\' AND LastName = \'\'{1}\'\' AND Email = \'\'{2}\'\'',
                new String[] {
                    FirstName==null?'':String.escapeSingleQuotes(FirstName.tolowercase()),
                    LastName==null?'':String.escapeSingleQuotes(LastName.tolowercase()),
                    Email==null?'':String.escapeSingleQuotes(Email.tolowercase())
                }
            );
        }
    }

    Map<UniqueKey, Lead> leads = new Map<UniqueKey, Lead>();
    for(Lead record:Trigger.new) {
        if(record.isconverted) {
            UniqueKey key = new UniqueKey(record.firstname, record.lastname, record.email);
            if(leads.containskey(key)) {
                record.addError('Duplicate lead conversion.');
            } else {
                leads.put(key, record);
            }
        }
    }
    String[] keys = new String[0];
    for(UniqueKey key:leads.keyset()) {
        keys.add(key.tostring());
    }
    String query = string.format(
        'SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact WHERE {0}',
        new String[] {
            String.join(keys, ' OR ')
        }
    );
    if(!leads.isempty()) {
        for(Contact record:Database.query(query)) {
            UniqueKey key = new UniqueKey(record.firstname, record.lastname, record.email);
            if(leads.containskey(key)) {
                leads.get(key).addError('Duplicate lead conversion.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Be careful with this code. It's carefully crafted to work around some "bugs" I found while writing this answer. I'm going to try and get those submitted.

Answer (score 2):

With new features, you don't even need any code. Use the duplicate matching rules in the declarative setup area to do this.