# Query to find out duplicate records on two fields

Tags: soql

I need to figure out the list of duplicate records based on two fields. That means suppose we have two duplicate records a and b, a.field_a__c = b.field_a__c and a.field_b__c = b.field_b__c and a.id != b.id. Is there anyway I can query this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14604/lead-convert-to-avoid-duplicate-values-to-contact/14622#14622) for information on how to catch multiple fields as duplicates (the answer mentioned uses three fields, but this can be expanded to any number of fields as you need). While this answer is not technically a duplicate, the answers you seek are already here on SFSE.

For a recap, basically, one solution is to use a wrapper class to mark duplicates. First, aggregate all possible values together, then query for them and place them into the wrapper class, then process the results. I've included the original code from the other example for you to peruse.

```
trigger BlockDupeLeadConvert on Lead (after update) {
    class UniqueKey {
        UniqueKey(string Firstname, String lastName, String email) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.email = email;
        }
        string FirstName, LastName, Email;
        integer hashCode() {
            return toString().hashCode();
        }
        boolean equals(Object o) {
            return toString() == ((UniqueKey)o).toString();
        }
        public override string toString() {
            return String.format(
                'FirstName = \'\'{0}\'\' AND LastName = \'\'{1}\'\' AND Email = \'\'{2}\'\'',
                new String[] {
                    FirstName==null?'':String.escapeSingleQuotes(FirstName.tolowercase()),
                    LastName==null?'':String.escapeSingleQuotes(LastName.tolowercase()),
                    Email==null?'':String.escapeSingleQuotes(Email.tolowercase())
                }
            );
        }
    }

    Map<UniqueKey, Lead> leads = new Map<UniqueKey, Lead>();
    for(Lead record:Trigger.new) {
        if(record.isconverted) {
            UniqueKey key = new UniqueKey(record.firstname, record.lastname, record.email);
            if(leads.containskey(key)) {
                record.addError('Duplicate lead conversion.');
            } else {
                leads.put(key, record);
            }
        }
    }
    String[] keys = new String[0];
    for(UniqueKey key:leads.keyset()) {
        keys.add(key.tostring());
    }
    String query = string.format(
        'SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact WHERE {0}',
        new String[] {
            String.join(keys, ' OR ')
        }
    );
    if(!leads.isempty()) {
        for(Contact record:Database.query(query)) {
            UniqueKey key = new UniqueKey(record.firstname, record.lastname, record.email);
            if(leads.containskey(key)) {
                leads.get(key).addError('Duplicate lead conversion.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why this is necessary is because unlike normal SQL, you can't simply write `select ... left join on a.field_a__c = b.field_a__c and a.field_b__c = b.field_b__c and a.id != b.id`. It doesn't work that way. The way around it is rather unfortunate, as you're likely to query many more records than you intend to in most cases. If you have very few values to choose from, you may even be forced to use extreme measures, like a formula field or even a batch class to flag the records as duplicate after the fact.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But this seems to query the whole table which in my case means 170k+ records. I am trying to narrow down the query to make it a little bit more reasonable. Making it a batch job doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: @LanceShi No, it's only looking for records that might possibly be a duplicate. This specific example builds a query like `select id, firstname, lastname, email from contact where (firstname='John' and lastname='Doe' and email='johndoe@gmail.com') or (firstname='Jane' and lastname='Smith' and email='janesmith@gmail.com')`. Only query what you need to find, and you should be okay.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. But the map is built on Trigger.new. In my case, it is not a trigger, it is a query which will query the whole table - Anyway, I have figured out how to narrow it down now. And your example is of great help.

Comment: As the string length increases as the number of records increase , will this have any impact on the SOQL query character limit. SOQL Characted limit is: 20000 per soql statement.  Please let me know if I am getting something wrong about the character limit

Comment: as I assume if a single record requires ~50 character then a list having nearly 500 records can easily cross the limit..

Comment: @karti Yes. The alternative is the slightly less accurate binding solution, something like: `Set<String> fn = new Set<String>(), ln = new Set<String>(), email = new Set<String>(); ... for(Contact record: [SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM Contact WHERE FirstName IN :fn AND LastName IN :fn AND Email IN :email]) { ... }` As you can see, it'll pull in records that don't match, but using binding this way circumvents the 20k character limit.